# MySql - Best way to do this kind of query

Tags: mysql

I need to return a single row with some datas taken from some tables not related each others.

So, for example, my actual queries are these (I done it trought a PHP script) :

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT trackid FROM tracklist WHERE usersub='".$_SESSION['nickname']."'",$mydb);
echo mysql_num_rows($query);
$query=mysql_query("SELECT trackid FROM comments WHERE usercom='".$_SESSION['nickname']."'",$mydb); 
echo mysql_num_rows($query);
$query=mysql_query("SELECT vote FROM vote WHERE uservote='".$_SESSION['nickname']."'",$mydb);
echo mysql_num_rows($query);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT datereg FROM users WHERE nickname='".$_SESSION['nickname']."'",$mydb);
echo mysql_result($query,0,'datereg');
```

But this will call the MySql server 4 times.
Whats your suggestion to better this situation?

Comment: Well you have 4 tables, ergo 4 DB calls :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [use](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) a `UNION`. And, btw, `mysql_result` [is poor](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php). And FFS don't forget to sanitize your inputs!

```
<?php
$nickname = mysql_escape_string($_SESSION['nickname']);

$sql = "
  SELECT COUNT(trackid) AS n FROM tracklist WHERE usersub='{$nickname}'
    UNION
  SELECT COUNT(trackid) FROM comments WHERE usercom='{$nickname}'
    UNION
  SELECT COUNT(vote) FROM vote WHERE uservote='{$nickname}'
    UNION
  SELECT datereg FROM users WHERE nickname='{$nickname}'
";

$result = mysql_query($sql, $db);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   echo $row['n'];
}
?>
```

I wouldn't really recommend this as it's a bit of a mess combining "count" values with a date in the same column, but you *can* do it. It's the direct answer to your question.

Comment: I think that `$nickname = mysql_escape_string($_SESSION['nickname']);` is not necessary! In fact that variable is stored by taking it from database (which is already filtered once insered on it). Thanks for the suggestions :)

Comment: @markzzz: Just because you take it out of the database doesn't mean it doesn't contain slashes or quotes.

Comment: Yes! I've filtered it before add it! Its a "nickname", so only [a-z], [0-9] and _ or .

Comment: @markzzz: Then there's no harm in being doubly safe. :) If nothing else, it's a good habit to get into. What if someone else manages to insert a non-filtered nickname into your database? Or your insertion routines make a mistake?

Comment: I Think that's difficult :) At least, the Host should be protected from external attack (I hope so). In any case yes, I could make a double safe...

Comment: Or at least, i could use `$_SESSION['nickname']=mysql_escape_string($_SESSION['nickname']);` at the beginning of my website, so I don't have to do this everytime :)

Comment: @markzzz: Possibly, though I prefer not to mutate session variables in arbitrary places, but to limit that to things like "login" functions.

Answer (score 2):

If the tables are not related then you will have to make 4 seperate calls

If the tables COULD be related by foreign keys then you could join them in some way and possibly cut down your sql calls

Ultimately though if you need all of the data then you'll have to request it from the database

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could create a fifth table and use it as an index.

If all the values { trackid, vote, datareg } are integers, the index table could contain three columns - nickname, value, and table.  When you add records to one of the other tables, add a corresponding record to the index table.

For example,
INSERT INTO vote (vote, uservote, ...) VALUES (123, 'abc', ...);
INSERT INTO myindex (nickname, nvalue, ntable) VALUES ('abc', 123, 'vote');

(I wouldn't actually store the table name as a string but as a numeric value, but you get the idea)

Then on a query, you just SELECT nvalue, ntable FROM myindex WHERE nickname = 'abc';
You will possibly get more than one row.

I think that this is a lot of work and you are better off sticking with the four original queries.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried combining the select statement together like

SELECT .. Actually.

Maybe you should normalise your database and set up links between your tables...

Edit :: And i'm not sure how you're preparing yourself against mysql injection, but be careful with where your $_SESSION[] comes from

Answer (score 0):

If all the selects return a single row:

```
$query=mysql_query("
    (SELECT trackid FROM tracklist WHERE usersub='".$_SESSION['nickname']."'") as tracklist,
    (SELECT trackid FROM comments WHERE usercom='".$_SESSION['nickname']."'") as trackid, 
    (SELECT vote FROM vote WHERE uservote='".$_SESSION['nickname']."'") as vote,
    (SELECT datereg FROM users WHERE nickname='".$_SESSION['nickname']."'") as datereg
"
```